# How to print out lists in a list

Tags: python-2.7

Note: code created in python 2.7

I am taking a robotics class in school and we are learning python.

The task was to take

`n = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]`

and print it out as such

`1`

`2`

`3`

`4`

`5`

`6`

`7`

`8`

`9`

When I tried my code out I got the error message

[image: Error message]

I tried looking at what this means online but I am just starting to learn python and I didn't understand any of the answers that I found.

What am I doing wrong? How do I fix my code?

[image: My full code]

First Post sorry about the mess

Answer (score 0):

## Reason why you get an error:

You get the error in the line

```
results.append(lists[numbers[each_list]])
```

because `numbers` is an integer and `numbers[each_list]` isn't a valid function. So instead use the square brackets correctly:

```
results.append(lists[numbers][each_list])
```

---

## Other Methods:

You don't really need to use range function:

```
n = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
for i in n:
    for j in i:
        print(j)
```

or a one liner:

```
print('\n'.join(str(j) for i in n for j in i))
```

---

Or if you are flattening a nested list:

```
n = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
def flat(lis):
    res = []
    for i in lis:
        for j in i:
            res.append(j)
    return res
flat_n = flat(n)
```

or a one-liner:

```
>>> n = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
>>> flat = lambda x: [j for i in x for j in i]
>>> flat(n)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

or just simply:

```
flat_n = [j for i in n for j in i]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7,8,9]]

def flatten(lists):
    results=[]
    for lists in n:
        for numbers in lists:
            results.append(numbers)
    return results
new_list =(flatten(n))

for num in new_list:
    print (num)


When Executed

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
>>>
```